# return dollar amount regex javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this extracted string and im trying to return the dollar amount.

```
var str = "5 Iphones in stock at $299 on 11/26";
var strNew = str.match(/^\$?[0-9]+/g);
strIwant = "$299"
```

It works but not always, it seems like its returning null when there is multiple numbers like in the example above, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why not just, `\$[0-9]+` as the pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression you were testing with indicates that the pattern must start at the beginning of your string (via the `^` character) which may explain why example strings you were testing against would sometimes return `null`.

In terms of matching whole dollar amounts (without decimals and cents) `\$[0-9]+` should suffice. Below is working example code which seems to fit your needs:

```
var strs = ["5 Iphones in stock at $299 on 11/26 and $500 on 11/27", 
            "5 Iphones in stock at $299 on 11/26",
            // this would be matched with your original regex
            "$200 worth of Iphones in stock at $299 on 11/26 and $500 on 11/27"];

strs.forEach(function(v) { console.log(v.match(/\$[0-9]+/g)); })
```

Which printed out to the console the results I had expected,

```
["$299", "$500"]
["$299"]
["$200", "$299", "$500"]
```

Comment: @Matt No worries, the best way to learn regular expressions is to keep practicing them. On a side note, take a peek at [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) which helps to illustrate what your expression is doing to help pinpoint why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the "$299" you have to use wrap the expression within "()"

If the dollar is always necessary, then the "?" is not needed

And finally, if it the amount can be in any part of the string then the "^" is wron

```
var str = "5 Iphones in stock at $299 on 11/26";
var strNew = str.match(/(\$[0-9]+)/g);
```

Then, strNew is now an array of the matched values. strNew = `["$299"]`

```
var str = "5 Iphones in stock at $299 on 11/26 and $199 off";
var strNew = str.match(/(\$[0-9]+)/g);
```

Then strNew = `["$299", "$199"]`;

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/\$(\d+)/g
```

This returns amount of dollars if the prize is in integer.

```
/\$(\d+)(\.\d+)?/g
```

This returns amount of dollars if the prize is in float or integer. If the prize is float, the will be two arryas, one with the amount of dollars and one with the amount of cents.